# Is there a way i can develop a Python GUI to control LabVIEW VIs?

Tags: python, software-design, labview

I am setting up a software, to be built on Python3, for test rigs and currently these rigs use National Instruments cRIO hardware and other NI hardware. System runs on Windows computer.

To control these hardware, we will need VIs and subVIs built on LabVIEW. I know LabVIEW comes with its own user interface, but I would still like to develop my GUI in python because not all rigs in the future will use NI hardware or LabVIEW. There can be MATLAB plugins in the future.

I've seen tutorials online where one could use python functions in LabVIEW VIs, but is there any reference point for me where I can use LabVIEW VIs and have the GUI built on Python?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You could consider then to implement NI hardware control via Python - because NI has API not just in LabVIEW for controlling its hardware: http://www.ni.com/product-documentation/53059/en/, https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019OgDSAU.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible architecture would be to use some combination of TCP/IP, UDP and web services, as appropriate for the type of communication you need to do. 
This also gives you the flexibility to move different parts of the I/O code between the cRIO (or another device) and the host PC, as the same protocols will work whether you're communicating to a different device or on the same machine.

The options are covered fairly well in chapter 4 of the NI [CompactRIO Developers' Guide](http://www.ni.com/pdf/products/us/fullcriodevguide.pdf) but in summary:

- TCP/IP for messages, commands, or streaming data where no data can be lost
- UDP for broadcasting updates where low latency is more important than 100% integrity
- Web services for accessing current values (tags) - I would say these are also appropriate for short messages or commands.

There are examples in LabVIEW for all of these and you should be able to implement the corresponding Python end of the communication without too much trouble once you understand the basics - and similarly, substitute MATLAB or something else for the LabVIEW code in the future (if you really must).

Bear in mind that what you can do with web services has changed a lot in LabVIEW over the last few years so if you look at any examples online do check that they're up to date with the latest capabilities.

Alternatively, I have no experience with this myself but you might want to look into [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), which has bindings available for [Python](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python), [LabVIEW](http://labview-zmq.sourceforge.net/) and many other languages.

Comment: Edited to add: ZeroMQ might also be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the best choice is likely direct implementation of a TCP/IP based communication, but if you wanted something simpler (particularly if your communication is in the style of "Here's a set of instructions to run a VI, run that VI and then give me the results") you might want to take a look at either

- The [Wiresmith CLI tool](https://github.com/JamesMc86/LabVIEW-CLI/) (the VI Package in Releases on GitHub is currently newer than that available through VIPM), or
- The NI CLI tool, installed by default in LabVIEW 2018 but available with support for versions since 2014 [Download links](http://www.ni.com/en-gb/support/downloads/software-products/download.ni-labview-command-line-interface.html), [Documentation](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvhowto/cli_running_operations/).

In particular, the Wiresmith tool uses TCP/IP to connect to a VI you specify (or exe), and can then have messages written back to the console using a simple VI.

I've recently been using this with SCons (a Python-based build system) and have found it quite useful, but that's likely a much simpler interface than a full test system.